# Sending two keyboards Reply and Inline KeyboardMarkup. Teleram bot on C#

Tags: c#, telegram

How to send Reply and Inline keyboards to a teleger bot in c#?

Looked at the interface IReplyMarkup but found Nothing that could help. Maybe there is some way to send the user two keyboards at once? In this task, me need to send two at once.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can first send a message containing ReplyMarkup, then delete it, and then you can send a message with InlineKeyboardMarkup

ReplyMarkup should stay